# Keep on click CSS changes after page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am using the Cookie Yes plugin with wordpress, and have everything working as it should except for one last piece.

We want the banner to always be at the top, and not overlapping the nav bar, so i had to add some extra CSS so it would stick to the top.

I added a JS function which when you click the confirm cookie link, and the banner disappears, the nav goes back to the top.

What i have found though, is when i refresh the page, the styles are lost, and there is a large gap at the top of the site, where the banner was.

How can i get it so it will keep these extra styles?   Here is a link to the [site](https://staging-buildertrendcom.temp312.kinsta.cloud/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#cookieToggle').on('change', function(){
    const value = $(this).prop('checked');
    onCookieSelection (value);    
 });

function onCookieSelection (val) {
    $('#divAcceptCookiesConfirm').toggle(val);
    $('#divAcceptCookiesReject').toggle(!val);
 }  
 $('#cookieToggle').prop( "checked", true );
  onCookieSelection(true);

 $('#wt-cli-accept-all-btn').on('click', function() {
    $('html.has-not-scrolled #desktop-header').css('top', '0px');
    $('#mobile-header').css('top', '0px');
    $('main').css('top', '0px');
          
   });
    $('#wt-cli-reject-btn').on('click', function() {
        $('html.has-not-scrolled #desktop-header').css('top', '0px');
        $('#mobile-header').css('top', '0px');
        $('main').css('top', '0px');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well as i dont know about how you are checking if cookie is set .

Lets assume that `is_cookie_set()` function returns true/false .
so if user has already accepted the cookie then it returns true.

So do something like this to fix that issue :

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if(is_cookie_set()){
            $('html.has-not-scrolled #desktop-header').css('top', '0px');
            $('#mobile-header').css('top', '0px');
            $('main').css('top', '0px');
        }
    }
```

Let me know if that works

Comment: Hello Prashanthth,  Adding that code did not work.  Does it have to include the name of the cookie?   when i check the browser i can see "CookieLawInfoConsent" has been set.